# How can I create a powerbi dax formula to look at dates and intervals and returns a boolean value based on conditions?

Tags: powerbi, dax, calculated-columns

I am trying to create a calculated column with boolean values that will look at a list of dates and names (these are timecard punches), and see if the first date that is associated with a name is within 1 year of the date in the current row. If it is, the value for that row in the columns should be true and if it isn't (and the following situation is not true), it should be false. Here's where I'm having trouble. I also want it to read true if the first date associated with that name following a gap of two years or more since the last date before the date that I'm calling the first date (even though there is a first date before that one, it is the first date since the gap) is within 1 year of the date in the current row.

For example, if John has dates listed from 03/25/2013-09/07/2017 and 05/02/2023-12/04/2023, I would want the row that represents 12/04/2023 to have true value in this column, just like it would if the only dates listed were from 05/02/2023-12/04/2023. I don't know much about powerbi so I have been trying to get chatgpt to help me but at this point it's confusing enough that I think I need humans involved because I can't explain it to chatgpt. I am perfectly okay if this is completely rewritten and uses totally different functions as long as it works.

Here is what we are working with. ID is the unique ID of the person. Start is the date and time of the beginning of the shift, I just use it for the date. With this formula, I get this error: A circular dependency was detected: TimeEntries[New Person].

```
New Person = 
VAR CurrentID = SELECTEDVALUE('TimeEntries'[ID])
VAR CurrentRowStart = SELECTEDVALUE('TimeEntries'[Start])
VAR PreviousRow =
    CALCULATETABLE(
        VALUES('TimeEntries'[Start]),
        FILTER(
            'TimeEntries',
            'TimeEntries'[ID] = CurrentID &&
            'TimeEntries'[Start] < CurrentRowStart
        )
    )
VAR FirstDate =
    IF(
        COUNTROWS(PreviousRow) > 0,
        MINX(PreviousRow, 'TimeEntries'[Start]),
        BLANK()
    )
VAR LastDate =
    IF(
        COUNTROWS(PreviousRow) > 0,
        MAXX(PreviousRow, 'TimeEntries'[Start]),
        BLANK()
    )
VAR GapDuration = DATEDIFF(FirstDate, CurrentRowStart, YEAR)
RETURN
    IF(
        DATEDIFF(CurrentRowStart, FirstDate, YEAR) < 1 ||
        (GapDuration >= 2 && DATEDIFF(CurrentRowStart, FirstDate, YEAR) >= 1),
        TRUE(),
        FALSE()
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood this correctly:

> I also want it to read true if the first date associated with that name following a gap of two years or more since the last date before the date that I'm calling the first date (even though there is a first date before that one, it is the first date since the gap) is within 1 year of the date in the current row.

But the following should get you going:

```
New Person = 
  var currentStart = [Start]
  var prevFilter = FILTER(ALLEXCEPT('TimeEntries', TimeEntries[ID]), 'TimeEntries'[Start] < currentStart)
  var firstD = CALCULATE(MIN('TimeEntries'[Start]), prevFilter)
  var lastD = CALCULATE(MAX('TimeEntries'[Start]), prevFilter)
  var firstGap = IF(NOT ISBLANK(firstD), YEARFRAC(firstD, currentStart, 1) )
  var lastGap = IF(NOT ISBLANK(firstD), YEARFRAC(lastD, currentStart, 1) )
  var firstLastGap = IF(NOT ISBLANK(firstD), YEARFRAC(firstD, lastD, 1) )

  RETURN SWITCH(TRUE(),
   NOT ISBLANK(firstGap) && firstGap <= 1, TRUE(),
   firstLastGap >= 2, TRUE(),
   FALSE()
)
```

**Fun fact or Top tip**
`DATEDIFF` Returns the number of **interval boundaries** between two dates.
So `DATEDIFF( YEAR(2022, 12, 31), YEAR(2023, 1, 1), YEAR)` returns `1` as it has crossed a year boundary.

Hence I used `YEARFRAC` above - see [YEARFRAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/yearfrac-function-dax)